# Python - write symbolic expression (sympy) to txt file

Tags: python, save, expression, sympy

What is the best way to write a symbolic expression to a txt file (so that I can use the symbolic expression after reading the txt file)?

Is there a sympy equivalent of numpy's savetxt() function for example?

for example:

```
from sympy import Symbol
a=Symbol('a')
b=Symbol('b')

y=a+3*b
```

How can I properly write and read y?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) library to store it to a file (as you can save most Python objects):

```
import pickle
with open("y.txt", "w") as outf:
    pickle.dump(y, outf)
```

You would later load it with

```
with open("y.txt") as inf:
    y = pickle.load(inf)
```

Comment: Note that `pickle` chokes on many SymPy expressions. `dill` does a better job.

Answer (score 12):

`str(expr)` in SymPy should save most of the information about your expression. The advantage is that it is human readable. The best way to load from it is to use `sympify()`, as opposed to just copy-paste or `eval`, because for example, `str(Rational(1, 2))` will give `1/2`, which will evaluate to `0.5` directly.

There is also a function `srepr()` (SymPy's version of `repr`) that gives a more verbose output.

One thing to be aware of is that neither saves information about assumptions on Symbols at the moment (`Symbol('x', real=True)`), so if you need that, you should use something like pickle or dill.

Comment: srepr does store assumption (at least by now)...

Comment: how do you load in something that you have saved with srepr?

Comment: @zltn.guba you can parse a string back to a sympy expression with `sympify` or `parse_expr`.

Comment: @asmeurer I think the problem is rather: how do you get back the symbols and use them again. Also what can you do when you have two different expressions, containing the same symbol? You can retrieve the symbols from the expression with free_symbol but how do you make sure that the same symbol can be used in both expressions again?

Comment: @zltn.guba SymPy treats two symbols that have the same name and assumptions as the same, so you can just recreate the symbol with `Symbol`. Also, it's better to ask a new question for things like this.